# TYPO3 tx_news multiple tags lists with same tag title not possible

Tags: typo3, tx-news

I use two tx_news plugins on separate pages in the same tree. I am using the tag search which works fine. However i want separate tag list for both. If i enter in the second list a tag with the same name of a tag in the first list TYPO3 adds a zero at the end. So "myTag" turns into "myTag0".

Unfortunately i can not trim the tag or replace the zero in the fluid template.

```
<f:link.page title="{tag.title}" pageUid="{settings.listPid}" additionalParams="{tx_news_pi1:{overwriteDemand:{tags: tag}}}">
  <v:format.trim content="{tag.title}" characters="O"></v:format.trim>
</f:link.page>
```

I need to have separate lists which allow same tag names, otherwise the tag count 
     ({tagUsageCount})

would be wrong and the tag search will not work properly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out https://github.com/georgringer/news/blob/master/Configuration/TCA/tx_news_domain_model_tag.php#L108-L116

```
    'title' => [
        'exclude' => false,
        'label' => $ll . 'tx_news_domain_model_tag.title',
        'config' => [
            'type' => 'input',
            'size' => 30,
            'eval' => 'required,unique,trim',
        ]
    ],
```

Remove the `unique` from the eval section of the tag title and you can store as many tags with the same name. You could differ those then by e.g. the pid or any other field in the tag record.

---

However regarding the trimming: I would go with a custom VH it the vhs one does not work.

Comment: you should not make direct change in extension table field, You can overwrite column config value from your own extension. like,
$GLOBALS['TCA']['tx_news_domain_model_tag']['columns']['title']['config']['eval'] = 'required,trim';